# jQuery .css sometimes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I fix problem with jQuery function ".css" which works only when it is triggred by user (console, button, ...) ?

I'm using interval in .ready function for trigger it but it dosn't work. However .html function is changing the text properly.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $.get("./getData", function(data)
        {
                $(".text").html("" + data + " %");
                $(".circle").css("border-width", "" + data + "px");
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Provide minimalistic sample on jsFiddle which reproduces your issue

Comment: Problem is not in the html() it is in css(). And removing or changind content of html do not make changes.

Comment: Your code looks fine if `data` is numeric value and you have element with class name `circle`

Comment: @DaanHeskes maybe he should've used `.text()` instead, but that line is syntactically valid JS and works fine with jQuery API.

Comment: What is `$(".circle").length`? What is `data.toString()`? It could be painting problems (you would need to repaint), but it's rare and by the way `"" + data` is useless.

Comment: $(".circle").length = 1 and data are always some int32. How can I repaint it ?

Comment: @JanSchwar Also have a look at `border-style` and `border-color` properties. To repaint try `$(".circle").addClass('repaint').removeClass('repaint');` and if that doesn't work put that in a `setTimeout` with `0` delay. Also, `data` might always be an int, but are you sure it's greater than `0`?

Answer (score 0):

Other border properties specified properly? Border color and weight? Its working fine when specified.

Comment: Function is working properly like when I use it manuály it works just fine. But this way just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, make sure `data` is numeric value and you have element with class name `circle`

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/TyxNQ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to call this function on window.onload.

```
 <script>
 function testFunction()
 {
   setInterval(function()
{
    $.get("./getData", function(data)
    {
            $(".text").html("" + data + " %");
            $(".circle").css("border-width", "" + data + "px");
    });
}, 1000);
 }

 window.onload=testFunction;

 </script>
```